# Toggle marginTop on mouseleave div

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle function that slides a div up and down.. But how can I make it toggle marginTop -200 on mouseleave?

Should I have a separate function for mouseleave?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item-40').toggle(

    function() {
        $('#slidenav').animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $('#slidenav').animate({
            marginTop: '-200px'
        }, 500);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Wasn't using `toggle()` this way deprecated?

Comment: One additional note is that before you start your next `.animate()` you may want to call `.stop(true, true)`.

Comment: @j08691 I can't see any deprecation notice despite it being in the `deprecated` category. I also can't see any reason for deprecation except for the naming collision.

Comment: @JanDvorak - http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ scroll down

Comment: @j08691 I know it's there, only I'm not sure why.

Comment: deprecated or not, it works. How can i inlcude a mouseleave into it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mouseleave` event on your `div` selector. Then apply the custom `toggleMargin` function I created for you (I used +-20px instead your desired value)

```
<div id="div"></div>

// CUSTOM TOGGLEMARGIN FUNCTION
var t = true;
jQuery.fn.toggleMargin=function(){
  var lastmargin = $(this).css('margin-top').replace("px", "");
  var newMargin;
  if(t){
    newMargin = parseInt(lastmargin)+20;
    t=false;
  }
  else{
    newMargin = parseInt(lastmargin)-20;
    t=true;
  }
  // Now apply the margi-top css attr
  $(this).css('margin-top', newMargin );
}

// LET'S TOGGLE MARGIN ON YOUR DIV
$('#div').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).toggleMargin();    
});​
```

**[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/UxVHe/2/)**

**UPDATE 22/12/12 **

Since I only have the code supplied try this:

[**TEST2**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxVHe/5/)

```
// CUSTOM TOGGLEMARGIN FUNCTION
var t = true;
jQuery.fn.toggleMargin=function(){
var lastmargin = $(this).css('margin-top').replace("px", "");
var newMargin;
if(t){
  newMargin = parseInt(lastmargin)+20;
  t=false;
}
else{
  newMargin = parseInt(lastmargin)-20;
  t=true;
}
// Now apply the margi-top css attr
$(this).css('margin-top', newMargin ); 
}

$('#slidenav').mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).toggleMargin();            
});

$('.menu-item-40').click(function(){
        $('#slidenav').toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '0'}, 500);
        });        
});
```

Comment: On which div selector do i add mouseleave?

Comment: On the one you want to change the margin-top. Watching your code I guess is `menu-item-40`. Or you can press F12 and select the div in order to get its `id`.

Comment: If you didn't manage to get it add more `html` code and explain a little better what you want to achieve and I will try to adapt my code to your requieriments.

Comment: I don't want to change the current code, I just want to add a mouse leave #slidenav function. Toggle should stay as it is..

Comment: Try to run the Test2. Click on link button to toggle the div and then do the mouse leave to toggle the margin-top.

Comment: a_maar, big thanks for trying! But it doesn't work at all! it just opens a new blank page. Why not just make another function that triggers on mouselave.